# CORS issue with Angularfire2 Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to use Angularfire2 (v5.0.0-rc.3), but am receiving CORS issues

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1beta1.Firestore/Listen/channel?gsessionid=w5AH2plIbmZY17fjCAsl4-KEpD1GjKtr&VER=8&RID=rpc&SID=bFGKTCIqerIWjB6AlU9X0Q&CI=0&AID=4&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=ul0vajwsa7m2&t=2
>   due to access control checks.

Here is my service which triggers this error

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

@Injectable()
export class ClientsService {
  private clientsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Client>;
  clients: Observable<Client[]>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.clientsCollection = afs.collection<Client>('clients');
    this.clients = this.clientsCollection.valueChanges();
  }

  updateClients = (params: any): Promise<Client[]> => {
    this.clientsCollection = this.afs.collection('clients')
    this.clients = this.clientsCollection.valueChanges()
    return this.clients.toPromise()
  }
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am just starting to write an app using angular firestore and now I'm getting this same error, but only on an iOS emulator..

Comment: I've found that moving firebase requests outside of my resolve and into the controller onInit gets rid of this problem. There is an open ticket on github issues for firebase: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/246#issuecomment-368228934